# Hibernate schema migration set naming strategy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Spring JPA application that uses `SpringNamingStrategy` by default, which is very close to `ImprovedNamingStrategy`.

I'm writing a helper that uses the hibernate classes to generate scripts for schema update.

```
    public class MigrationHelper {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
            DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
                    .url("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL")
                    .username("mqcompare")
                    .password("mqcompare")
                    .build();

                LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
                sessionFactory.scanPackages("com.company.mqmsgcom.entity");
                //this doesen't work
                sessionFactory.setProperty("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringNamingStrategy");
                Dialect dialect = new Oracle10gDialect();
                DatabaseMetadata metadata = new DatabaseMetadata(dataSource.getConnection(), dialect, sessionFactory);
                List<SchemaUpdateScript> scripts = sessionFactory.generateSchemaUpdateScriptList(dialect, metadata);

                Formatter formatter = FormatStyle.DDL.getFormatter();
                for (SchemaUpdateScript script : scripts) {
                   System.err.println(formatter.format(script.getScript()) + ";");
                }
        }
    }
```

Script reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942217/generate-a-database-update-scripts-with-hibernate-spring)

How can I set the naming strategy in this code?

Edit: Hibernate version is 4.3.11 Final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy` is used for `JPA`. You can set a naming strategy by `LocalSessionFactoryBuilder#setNamingStrategy()`.

Looks like, there is not a property in Hibernate 4 to set a naming strategy to `Configuration` as a property.